# Excel VBA - Create loop for opening files

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below for opening files.  Specifically, it prompts to open 12 different files corresponding to each month of the year.

While the code works as is, it seems excessively long and I would assume could be shortened with a loop.  However, I am not sure how to write this.

Any help is appreciated.

```
'Intialize workbooks
    Dim myFile As String, monthSumJan As Workbook, monthSumFeb As Workbook, monthSumMar As Workbook, monthSumApr As Workbook, monthSumMay As Workbook, monthSumJun As Workbook, monthSumJul As Workbook, monthSumAug As Workbook, monthSumSep As Workbook, monthSumOct As Workbook, monthSumNov As Workbook, monthSumDec As Workbook
    Dim Jan As Worksheet, Feb As Worksheet, Mar As Worksheet, Apr As Worksheet, May As Worksheet, Jun As Worksheet, Jul As Worksheet, Aug As Worksheet, Sep As Worksheet, Oct As Worksheet, Nov As Worksheet, Dec As Worksheet
    ChDir "C:\Users\stefan.bagnato\Desktop\Monthly Performance Summary"
    'January
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumJan = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Jan"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'February
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumFeb = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Feb"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'March
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumMar = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Mar"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'April
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumApr = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Apr"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'May
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumMay = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "May"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'June
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumJun = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Jun"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'July
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumJul = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Jul"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'August
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumAug = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Aug"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'September
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumSep = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Sep"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'October
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumOct = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Oct"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'November
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumNov = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Nov"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
    'December
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumDec = ThisWorkbook
    ActiveSheet.name = "Dec"
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
```

Comment: And that's where( and why) you use function(s). learn about them : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your workbooks in an array if you need to reference them later.

```
' Array of Monthly Summary Workbook objects
Dim MonthSum(1 To 12) As Workbook

'Application.GetOpenFileName can return a path as a String, 
' or `False` if the user hits Cancel, so the variable should be a Variant
Dim File As Variant

' Set Current Directory
ChDir "C:\Users\stefan.bagnato\Desktop\Monthly Performance Summary"

' Loop through each month
Dim Month As Integer
For Month = 1 To 12

    ' Show Open File Dialog
    File = Application.GetOpenFilename

    ' Stop the loop if user hits cancel
    If File = False Then
        Exit For
    End If

    ' Open selected file, store Workbook object in the MonthSum array
    ' Workbooks.Open() returns the Worbook object of the opened file. 
    Set MonthSum(Month) = Workbooks.Open(File)

    ' Set Sheet Name, MonthName() returns the name of the month
    ' given its number. The true parameter indicates the name
    ' should be abbreviated to 3 letters
    ActiveSheet.Name = MonthName(Month,True)

    ' Call your custom macro
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary

Next

' Do some other stuff

' Close the Workbooks
For Month = 1 To 12
    ' If User hit Cancel, MonthSum(Month) might not be a workbook object
    ' so check and make sure it's not Nothing before calling Close on it.
    If Not MonthSum(Month) Is Nothing Then 
        MonthSum(Month).Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @TaylorScott. What makes you think it's not VBA? If it's how I defined the month names array, I assure you this works. Try it!

Comment: Drew, a more correct way to say what I was trying to articulate is that this is not *base* VBA and your approach does not really make sense. The method for declaring an array that you are using depends on making a range object and coercing that into a set of strings, which can only be done in Excel VBA. Beyond that the effect can be acheived with the built-in function `MonthName(1,Abbreviate:=True)`

Comment: @Drew Chapin, this works.  Thank you.  Quick question: At the end of the entire set of code, I had a snippet to close all of the workbooks after I extracted the data.  `monthSumJan.Close` would close January.  Now it does not work.  Looking through your code, it looks like the workbook variable name is still monthSumJan.  Is this wrong?

Comment: No. You would loop through the `MonthSum` array again to close. I updated the answer with an example to show how to close the workbooks at a later time.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: Note... If you just individually wanted to close January's, but not the others you would do `MonthSum(1).Close...`.

Comment: Got it.  I have another question related to this overall subject, and I know it will be using some variant of the code you provided.  Do you want me to PM it to you?  Or pose it as a new question so you can answer get the acceptance?  (Note: I have tried to figure it out on my own, but no luck yet..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174669/discussion-between-sbagnato-and-drew-chapin).

Answer (score 2):

A quick shot would be

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 12
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    Set monthSumJan = ThisWorkbook
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary
Next i
```

Loops are explained [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-for-loop/)

You are aware that you do not check if the user presses cancel in the dialog GetOpenFilename, aren't you?

UPDATE:

As the complete relevant code is not known do sth like that

```
Dim actWkb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 12
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Set actWkb =  Workbooks.Open(myFile)
    Call ECHIBasicMonthlySummary(actWkb)
Next i
```

and adjust

```
Sub ECHIBasicMonthlySummary(ByVal monthSh As Workbook)

' adjust it your code here
' you need to use monthSh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I am aware.  My only question regarding the code you provided is how would I be able to have a different month variable set for each book?  The first workbook would be "monthSumJan".  The second should be "monthSumFeb", and ect.

Comment: You can also use something along the lines of `ActiveSheet.Name = MonthName(i,True)` to get the names handled

Comment: Using this code, and your original - `ThisWorkbook` will always refer to the workbook containing the code.  To refer to the opened workbook  you'd use `Set monthSumJan = Workbooks.Open(myFile)`.